# Crystal Reports doesn't allow me to select datasource

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, datasource

I'm working on windows forms application. I want to give crystal reports a .net object as datasource, my "product" class.
it worked for the first report and its working fine.

the problem is when i want to create another report, on "Standard Report Creation Wizard" when i navigate to project data > .net objects > [my class name] and try to include in to my report, this window pops up :|

[image]

what this window is asking me for?

I created another project and created a class and report and again it worked fine! so how can i make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, don't go through this avenue. It's much too complicated to set the datasource like this! Instead, go ahead and create the .rpt file, and from the designer in Visual Studio, you can view the database expert. From there, you can add any of your .NET objects.

I've set up a class for you to test as well. I just plugged this into my Reporting project and it works.

```
public class DummyReportClass
    {
        public string FieldOne { get; set; }
        public string FieldTwo { get; set; }
        public string FieldThree { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: the database expert shows me the same window, I think the problem is the database expert does not recognize that this is actually a .net object and not a database table.

Comment: Make sure you compile the application again after the creation of your Custom Types, and make sure they contain all the properties you need for the report. They must be properties, not fields. To validate all your data sources, you can right click, and select "verify database", and it should bring everything up to date. Also, to make sure that Crystal is able to find everything without any hassles, I recommend leaving all .rpt files at the top-level directory of your project. Don't store them in any folders until you're sure all namespace issues will be resolved.

Comment: Oh, and I recommend using a blank report.

Comment: I did what you said, still no result. its making me crazy :(

Comment: i've add a dummy class to my answer for your to try. add this class to your report project. rebuild your project. right-click on .Net Objects from your database expert, and select "refresh." and add the class from there. see if you can now select properties from the dummy class into your report.

Comment: I see. What happens when you check "use dataset from class"?

Comment: when i select the class and then click on ">>" button, the same window I provided its screenshot on above pops up asking me for .xml file.

Comment: Ado XML is what you want. XML is how Crystal maps your custom types to the report.  Try browsing to the folder that contains your report namespace using the wizard.

Comment: Scratch that, you shouldn't really need to do anything beyond the steps I listed earlier. Try creating a new project, and add nothing but the dummy class and a blank report object. See if it works at that point.

Comment: I tried that earlier, back then it listed the xml files fields. i even tried opening my class .cs file ( :D ) but it didn't work.

Comment: I just created a new project in Visual Studio 2013, and went through the steps I listed. Everything went off without a hitch.

Comment: it works on new projects! but not on my current one.

Comment: do you think i should use dataset?

Comment: Try creating a new blank report in your current project, and the dummy class. Everything at the Top level, using the default namespace provided by VS. What happens then?

Comment: this is exactly what i did earlier. it keeps asking for ado.net xml file

Comment: Something may have been corrupted in your current project. Is it possible to migrate to a new Solution?

Comment: that's gonna take time, I have to present my project tomorrow.

Comment: This is a school project?

Comment: no its for client, the problem is reports is important for my client.

Comment: I understand. I'm currently Searching for ways to resolve this issue. The last time this happened to me, I moved my report objects to a new project, and was able to make my deadline. If that is not possible for you, then the only way to proceed is to provide that XML information to the reporting framework.

Comment: now i was able to do it using dataset. i think I'm done using .net objects along with crystal.

Comment: I'm looking at alternatives as well. Crystal Reports has been extremely unstable, even randomly crashing on my end users. Microsoft Access seems to be more reliable, with a much greater c# library to work with.